# If every buyer in a futures contract has a corresponding seller, how can open interest ever be an odd number?

Tags: futures, open-interest

I'm new to trading so pardon the entry-level question:

Here's a screenshot of today's settlement for the September 2021 S&P futures contract on the Chicago Mercantile Exchange:

[image]

The prior day's open interest is 2,584,125. If, in the futures market, every long has a corresponding short, how do we end up in a situation where the open interest is an odd number? Shouldn't the open interest always be even, seeing as how there's always a long and short side to every open contract?

Thanks for the help.

TRC

Comment: One long and one short create one contract. Closing the long and covering the short eliminate one contract. Open interest is the net balance. Same idea as options.

Comment: Open Interest is the total number of Long positions, and is also equal to the total number of Short positions. (It is not the sum of the Longs and the Shorts, as you seem to assume).

Comment: Ah, I see. Since the CME is always the counterparty (the buyer for every seller and the seller for every buyer), I incorrectly assumed that if you open a long and it's matched with my opening short, there'd be two contracts in existence, thus open interest would increase by two. Now I understand that this would only increment the OI value by +1. Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A buy to open and a sell to open increase open interest by 1, not 2 (both sides of one contract are created). A buy to close and a sell to open, as well as a buy to open and a sell to close, do not effect open interest (one contract side is created and another is closed). A buy to close and a sell to close reduce open interest by 1 (both sides of a contract are closed).

So it's perfectly reasonable for open interest to be an odd number.

Comment: Thanks, bud. Makes sense.